# In a reversible heat exchange, does the system and reservoir need to almost have the same temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, reversibility

In order for a process which involves heat flow from surroundings to the system to be reversible, is it necessary that the temperature difference between the system and surroundings be very small at every time during the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it necessary that the temperature difference between the system and
> surroundings be very small at every time during the process?

Yes, because that is the only way the system can be in equilibrium with its surroundings at every stage of the process. It it is disequilibrium that causes a process to be irreversible. Thermal disequilibrium is due to temperature difference, mechanical disequilibrium due to net forces or and pressure differences, and so forth. On the other hand it is disequilibrium that drives all real processes. This is why reversible processes do not exist, but can only be approximated.

Moreover, reversible heat transfer processes, could they be achieved, would be extremely impractical. When you decrease the temperature difference you lower the rate of heat transfer, all other things being equal. The lower the rate of heat transfer the longer it takes the to transfer a given amount of heat. In the limit when the temperature difference approaches zero it takes an infinite amount of time to transfer a given quantity of heat.

For example the Carnot cycle, which includes two reversible isothermal processes, is the most efficient in producing work for a given heat input. But the rate of work done (power output) for the Carnot cycle approaches zero in the limit. The Carnot cycle is an ideal construct in terms of setting an upper limit on the maximum possible efficiency of any heat engine. But as someone once said, if you put a Carnot engine in your car you would get fantastic fuel economy, but pedestrians would be passing you by.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Spontaneous macroscopic heat flow is always irreversible as it involves difference of temperatures. However, the lower the difference of temperature, the closer the process is to being reversible. In theory, if the difference becomes zero and some heat still transfers, which has to be allowed theoretically, the process is reversible. But it is very hard/impossible to achieve this in practice for large amounts of heat.